# Standford moss - text expansion doesn't work as input

Tags: bash

I am trying to automate some plagiarism check with the Stanford' Moss plagiarism checker.

I have a list of files in a variable that I which to expand in the moss function call

```sh
$ files="test\ 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.cpp test\ 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.cpp test\ 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.h test\ 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.h"
$ echo $files
$ moss -l cc -d $files
Checking files . . . 
File test\ does not exist. Request not sent.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Bonus info**

MOSS needs the inputs to not be quoted and therefore the escape character for spaces are needed.

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for some background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very briefly, the backslashes produced *by* the parameter expansion are not removed during quote removal: they are passed as part of the argument to `moss`, so `moss` sees the following arguments following `-d`:

```
test\ 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.cpp
test\ 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.cpp
test\ 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.h
test\ 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.h
```

rather than the intended arguments

```
test 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.cpp
test 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.cpp
test 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.h
test 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.h
```

The solution is to use an *array* to store multiple arguments that may include whitespace. The shell does not perform word-splitting on the elements produced by an appropriate array expansion.

```
files=(
    "test 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.cpp"
    "test 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.cpp"
    "test 1/submissions/uid1/2_6.h"
    "test 1/submissions/uid2/2_6.h"
)

moss -l cc -d "${files[@]}"
```

Instead of the array expanding as a single string whose elements are separated by a single space, it expands to *multiple* words, each of which is treated as a single quoted string. As such, no further word-splitting is applied to each word.

Comment: I had done this previously and gone away from the method, later the spaces appeared and I forgot the proper way of doing things, thanks!